How do I safely remove a mystery cast iron pipe in my basement?
I have a mystery 1¾" cast iron pipe (outside diameter) in my basement. It's ugly and rusting, and I want to remove it. I want to know what's in there before I start opening it up, but I'm out of ideas as to what it could be.
It has a black, rubbery (and oily in some places) coating along most of it. It comes in through the foundation in the basement below the outside grade, goes up to the basement ceiling, then runs along the wall for about 12 feet. Then it reduces into short 1¼" pipe that's capped off. The house is in Oregon as was built in 1930.
It's too big to be a water line or gas line (and the local gas co says there has never been gas at the house), and too small to be drain, waste, or vent.
I also don't believe it's an oil fill pipe. There used to be an oil tank in the opposite side of the basement. The old oil tank had a copper fuel line running to the old oil furnace. It has had oil since at least 1959, and was probably coal before that. I removed both the tank and furnace. There aren't any other (buried) tanks on the property either.
That leaves ... ? I don't know what. I'm certain it's not fuel oil related, which is probably the worst thing it could be (followed closely by a 1¾" water line under full city pressure). Is there a safe way to open up this unknown pipe so I can get rid of it?




Update: Thanks for all the responses.
I'm intrigued by the idea that it might be coal gas. The house is in NE Portland. I know there was coal gas in Portland, so maybe it's possible. The pipe enters on the street side of the house.
It's around 3 feet below grade on the outside, and I believe I have enough room to dig it up. That will at least tell me if it's capped off on the outside, or if the pipe goes off in some other direction, or connected to a big oil tank that was missed by the tank locator people. If nothing else, I'd rather try to open it outside - better to have coal gas, oil, or whatever leak out all over the front yard than in the basement.
I've also called 811, maybe the gas co or someone will be able to help identify it (though I think they don't find abandoned pipes, just active ones).

Though there is another oil line, I'd guess, from the description, it was an old oil line, no longer used. If you can uncap it and probe inside, you might find some old oil, half turned to tar, that would clinch that guess.

If it is not too far below grade where it goes outside, perhaps it can be dug down to to see where it goes. Most likely it was something that it was bringing something into the house but because of it being a pipe that can rust with ground contact and moisture, it failed. All it takes is one threaded section to fail, (the weak points) and at the most, there are joints every 20 feet, if not closer. Another idea, is if there is a tracer connected to the pipe to send a charge, so a detector can find its path inground.

It strikes me as odd that an oil line would be run up to the ceiling, or be that large a diameter.  Is there any indication from holes in the floor above what might have been present earlier?  What room is above the end of the pipe?  (Another Seth supporting Two Spaces For America.)

Since someone took the trouble to cap it off, it might indicate that it could be still "live".

The way the pipe turns away from the wall where it is capped makes me think there was a gas meter there. They used to be mounted indoors high up. The gas lines were also low-pressure and over an inch in diameter.

The more I look at the photos, the more they look like gas to me.   And of all your data points, the one I value least is the gas company having no records.  Given the age of this, I wouldn't give that any value.  You could look at history books, deeds, and other records and documents to see when gas service was installed on your street.   If it was there for example in the 1930s the house may have had gas for 20 or 30 years before converting to electric + oil, and your gas company today may have no record of any of that.

Some older homes had water cisterns in the basement, it could be the supply line?

@HABO if anything that seems a bit small for a heating oil supply to me; IIRC the ones at my parents house are 2" in diameter; it's large to allow for rapid filling of the tanks by the delivery truck.  They also are run along the ceiling to be out of the way until they drop down into the person tall storage tanks.

Steel pipe dimensions are obnoxious. "Nominal size" 1-1/4 pipe is 1.66" OD so that's probably what you're looking at. Nominal 1" is 1.3" OD. These are common sizes for low-pressure natural gas in a large home built today, but would have been very oversize for natural gas in that era. I couldn't easily find any information about typical pipe sizing for coal gas service.

Is your question "what is it" or "how do I remove it"?  It seems so far, all answers address "what is it" only.

If you believe that the pipe is coming from outside the home (and not to a tank underneath the house) you could call 811 (Dig Safely phone number) to see if they can identify the utilities and pipes coming into the home. Maybe they can tell you if it is a coal gas pipe.

Since someone took the trouble to cap it off, it might indicate the other end is sitting wide open and they got tired of mice using it as a highway.  (Or just tired of ground water seeping in through it.) Or someone just thought it was unsightly. Or... maybe it's "live".

@gerrit: How to remove it is obvious: get an angle grinder and chop it to bits, then cement up the hole. - The OQ is "How do I safely remove it?" The key to knowing what is safe is knowing what it is, and what needs to be done before chopping.

It is most likely a coal gas delivery pipe.
Coal gas was in common use in parts of Oregon in the 1930's. If your house is in a town or city it was probably fitted for coal gas when it was built.
The pipe is noticeably larger than a modern natural gas pipe because coal gas had a considerably lower caloric density than natural gas, so a correspondingly larger volume was needed. Also, coal gas was usually supplied at what we would now consider an anemic pressure, so large pipes were needed for an adequate flow rate.
The pipe was coated with a rubbery tar meant to prevent rust and to seal up any small leaks. Coal gas contains carbon monoxide so even a modest amount can be lethal.
Your current gas utility has no record of this pipe or the network that it was part of because they never delivered coal gas and never used this pipe. When they installed natural gas service they just capped the coal gas pipe and abandoned it.
See if you can find historical records of a coal-gas (aka town-gas) utility at your location. That may tell you when the pipe network was capped off and abandoned at the supply end.

Interesting!   Seth: this stuff doesn't lend itself well to internet searches.  Most towns have a historian.  Go to your town library, ask old-timers, look at local records, maps, etc.    Join Facebook Groups of old-timers from your town and ask questions there.  Your town may even have a history book!.  Or, look at Google Books and such for historical gossip columns, with tidbits like "with the advent of coal gas, the Lady's Club Thursday meetings would extend well into the night".

You could also ask neighbors who've lived in their houses for a long time if their houses have had similar piping, and if they happen to know what it was from?

It could be that the house originally was heated with coal gas, and when it was converted to oil heat, the coal gas was kept just for cooking (and thus the reduced diameter at the end of the run).  Also: the "other" end may be open and ready to bring groundwater into the basement.

It's fuel or water.  You seem to have ruled out all the obvious ideas. Unfortunately, one of your guesses is wrong, and the easy answer is buried with a long-previous owner.
I can't tell you what it actually is, but I can give some suggestions on how to investigate:

If it's a street-side wall, that's a clue to water or gas.  Could be the water service line and water meter were replaced.  If so it's probably disconnected.
Could be the gas company is wrong.  They have no records of serving your house, that doesn't mean there was never gas.
You say there are no oil tanks.  Did you hire the tank-finder person?  If not, you could do that.  Not too expensive and a lot easier than digging it up.
Dig it up and trace it.  You  don't have to trench, use signal tracer to find its direction and post hole digger in critical places to confirm.
Map all the underground utilities 360 degrees around your house.  Keep watch of the street and neighbors' yards.  Whenever you see underground utilities being marked out, add them to your map.  Do this for several years, and eventually you will have an accurate map of all utilities including ones that may have once served your house but no longer.  This might show you how water or gas once entered your house.


I don't think houses in the 1930's generally had the electrical service to support electric cooking. I would expect to see gas service even with oil heating.

@David42 for various reasons I'm tending to think it's a gas pipe, and I've changed my answer a little so I'm not discounting that possibility.

yes, i like the comment on the question that services and companies have changed over the decades, and so have addresses.  I can remember very very well when my apartment changed from a single gas meter for the building to separate unit meters...... because my unit was assigned the original meter & account and we started getting estimated bills for like $1000 we had to contest every month

Supplementary to other answers which suggest probable reasons that the pipe exists:
When you're ready to remove it, rather than going directly at it with an angle grinder, first drill a small hole so that if anything comes out you can quickly plug it with a screw.
For softer metals, I would recommend using a self-tapping screw as the stand-by filler, but that won't bite in cast iron.  You might be better using something like brass, so that the screw itself deforms to the hole.  You don't need to worry about ever needing to remove it.
A possible alternative that I've not tried would be a blind rivet, but that requires a much larger hole and there's no guarantee that the pin will remain in place once pulled, so you'd need a self-tapper of the pin diameter as well.

Actually, if the screw threads on the end-cap are still operable, you may be able to open it gently as the test, rather than drilling a hole.  That would be much simpler, assuming they are not seized up beyond operation.

Blind rivet is a pretty good idea. You're probably familiar only with the more common open style of blind rivet: these are a hollow tube with the pin inside which could in theory pull out. But there also are closed blind rivets. These are capped at the back; they seal up tight with no worry about leakage around the pin.

I would also strongly suggest that if you can't remove the pipe completely, you should re-cap it after cutting. Leaving it open runs the risk of a nasty surprise down the line.

Consider the angles of the pipe. It looks like they are rectangular? And they are running at the ceiling... if it is an influx pipe, it leaves gas as the only candidate, doesn't it? Also the cap is a hint to that.
Influx of a liquid like oil or water would not run up into the house (well, water has to actually).
If it is some outflux pipe for a liquid, it has to be mounted with a gradient to ensure water or oil flowing inside (considering there was a influx from inside the house through this pipe to some tank outside). And outflux for a gas does not make much sense.
Did you try hitting it with a crowbar or something and hear the tone it makes? Does it "ching" (connected to some tank) or is it "dull" (probably dead end)?
Is it possible to dig a hole on the outside wall at this position? Maybe this gives clues to where it led.
Maybe they had an isolated, external, (overground) fuel/gas tank in the garden (is there enough space outside?) and therefore the gas provider does not know about it.
